# Sails.js 1.0 breaks fresh install

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, node-modules

I had no problem using Sails 1.0 . I did not install or delete anything new on pc when this problem begun. I reinstalled Windows as well and still have same problem:

```
dvs@dvs-PC MINGW64 /d/
$ clear

dvs@dvs-PC MINGW64 /d/
$ node -v
v6.11.5

dvs@dvs-PC MINGW64 /d/
$ npm install sails@beta -g
C:\Users\dvs\AppData\Roaming\npm\sails -> C:\Users\dvs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js
C:\Users\dvs\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- sails@1.0.0-38


dvs@dvs-PC MINGW64 /d/
$ sails new exampleproject
C:\Users\dvs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:1237
    );//parley(…)
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dvs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\machine\lib\build.js:7:24)

dvs@dvs-PC MINGW64 /d/
$
```

Comment: Have you tried not using beta, but just `npm install sails -g`

Comment: This is the sort of problem that should be filed as a bug report on the GitHub repo. It would be much more likely for you to find the help you need there.

Comment: I will try there thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@t-st-os Just published a fix for this in a nested dependency.  It was a [Node 6 compatibility issue](https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails?at=59f4e4504ff065ac1889e612) I introduced in the beta earlier this week :/ (sorry!)

To pick up this fix in your app:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```